# How do I enter commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried all the cheats it gives you but none of them work.
Do you need to keep the `<` or `[`? Do you need to add spaces?
How do you change your game mode?

Comment: Type /help to see the list of available commands. If the list is empty, you are either on a server or your single player world is created with cheats disabled.

Comment: To change gamemodes: /gamemode 0 for survival, /gamemode 1 for creative and /gamemode 2 for adventure.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you are using the commands on the [WIKI](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands).

First of all, check if you have cheats enabled in your singleplayer world.

And examples of how you input a command. Name of player will be `test` (use YOUR player name):

Commands must be prefixed by a slash /

```
difficulty <peaceful | easy | normal | hard>
```

To set the difficulty to hard, you would type:

```
/difficulty hard
```

---

```
give <playername> <item> [amount] [metadata]
```

to give yourself a stack (64) of wooden planks, you would type:

```
/give test 5 64
```

5 is the data value of wooden planks. Refer to this [wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values) to get the values.

Comment: You may want to add that the `< >` brackets mean "the following value is required", and the `[ ]` brackets mean "the following value is optional".

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to "cheat" in minecraft. If you are talking about adding items to the game, you can do this in vanilla by typing the following commands:

```
/give <playername> <item> [amount]
```

So, you'd remove the "<>" and the "[]" when writing this in the console. It would look like the following:

```
/give Reallygoodpie 1 64
```

So this would give me the item with the data value of `1` and it would give me 64 of these. Data values are found here: [Data Values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values)

In order for the commands to work, you would need to enable cheats before you create your world. If you have already created your world and you are not sure if you have enables cheats press <kbd>esc</kbd> and then `open to LAN`. An interface will pop up and you need to enable cheats. Do note that this will open up your world to any computer connected to your local network.

More commands can be found here: [Minecraft Commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands)

There are also several mods available that allow "cheats". You can install [Too Many Items](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-162-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-jul-30-fixesupdates/) which is a mod that allows you to spawn any item you want through the use of an interface. You can literally spawn anything that is in the game from dirt to mob spawners. There is also an alternative mod called Not Enough Items.

Answer (score 2):

Are cheats enabled?  If not then that is your problem.  If they are then you need to put a / before the command.

Comment: Actually, I don't know about other variants, but the "/" is inserted automatically when you press the "console" key (which is bound to "/" by default, but as I re-bound it to something else, "/" is inserted nevertheless.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (do not type `[` `]`s)

```
/gamemode creative [Your username here]
```

Then just do what you want with command blocks; for example:

```
/give [Username] 137
```